# How to replace a comma "," with "||" in a list

Tags: replacement

I have a list of equations:

```
dene = {x1== 0.2, x2== 0.4, x3==0.5};
```

I would like to convert this list into a rule:

```
iki = {ToRules[x1==0.2 || x2==0.4 || x3==0.5]} // Flatten
```

which works. Since my list of equations is a very long list, I'd like to use some Mathematica function.

I have tried two options to make "dene" a rule: either eeplace "==" with "->" or substitute "," with "||". I could not do any of these options work, although I've spent quite some time on the problem. I need your help.

Comment: `{ToRules[Or @@ {x1 == 0.2, x2 == 0.4, x3 == 0.5}]}`?

Comment: `Rule @@@ {x1 == 0.2, x2 == 0.4, x3 == 0.5}` ?

Comment: Both answers work for me, though @Accidenta's answer is more compact.

Comment: I think it's good to point out here that replacing comma's in expressions is not possible in Mathematica. The comma is a delimiter in expressions and does not represent an infix notation for a system symbol (unlike, e.g., `;` which is short for `CompoundExpression`). You can play games with pretty much everything else, but comma's are basically untouchable unless you start converting expressions back and forth between strings (which is generally not how you want to program). Instead, you always want to find out what heads you need to transform. And if you want to splice things, use `Sequence`.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: How about the Edit/Find button in MMA menu?

Comment: @Peter: The question is to automatically replace "," with "||" or replace "==" with "->" to create a rule for substitution..

Comment: @user64494: what is MMA menu? Can you give more information on how to use it?

Comment: This is the second line in an MMA notebook which contains the buttons  File, Edit, Insert, Format, Cell, Graphics, Evaluation, Palettes, and Help. Don't hesitate to ask for further explanationin need.

Comment: @user64494: I knew this replacement but my problem was not one-by-one replacement, it was an automated replacement with a rule function.  This problem now has a definite answer above.  Thanks for your reminding me this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Much like @AccidentalFourierTransform's comment and @Pillsy's answer, you can also replace the heads but on all levels.

```
{x1 == 0.2, x2 == 0.4, x3 == 0.5} /. Equal -> Rule
```

> {x1 -> 0.2, x2 -> 0.4, x3 -> 0.5}

A multi-level example

```
Array[x[##] == {##} &, {2, 2}]
% /. Equal -> Rule
```

> {{x[1, 1] == {1, 1}, x[1, 2] == {1, 2}}, {x[2, 1] == {2, 1}, 
>     x[2, 2] == {2, 2}}}
>
> {{x[1, 1] -> {1, 1}, x[1, 2] -> {1, 2}}, {x[2, 1] -> {2, 1}, 
>     x[2, 2] -> {2, 2}}}

Answer (score 6):

Here is a simple function that does what I think you want.

```
makeRules[p : {_Equal ..}] := Rule @@@ p
```

Then

```
dene = {x1 == 0.2, x2 == 0.4, x3 == 0.5};
makeRules[dene]
```

> ```
> {x1 -> 0.2, x2 -> 0.4, x3 -> 0.5}
> ```

Comment: All the answers work for me, your as well. For my purpose, a simple replacement rule was needed. Your answer is much more advanced than I need but a nice structural solution.

Comment: @Tebernus. In practice, it will often be simpler just to write `Rule @@@ ...` but you said in your question that you would like a function.

Comment: Yes, in my text I used a wrong term "function", with which I meant any solution in layman's language. Since I am not a programmer, I possibly misinformed experts in this area. Sorry for that. Regards, Tebernus

Answer (score 5):

This is a good use for [`Cases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Cases.html) with a level specification, which allows you to use rules and pattern matching to create rules! The level spec helps if you have deeper nesting of `Or` expressions:

```
expr = x1 == 0.2 || x2 == 0.4 || x3 == 0.5;

Cases[expr, lhs_ == rhs_ :> {lhs -> rhs}, Infinity]
(* {{x1 -> 0.2}, {x2 -> 0.4}, {x3 -> 0.5}} *)
```

Comment: This is a good answer for pattern recognition.